# Pytorch Import Error when deploying django on AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My django app works locally. When i try to deploy it and then open it on AWS, i get the following error:

[image]

I included torch==1.5.1 in my requirements.txt

Requirements.txt:

[image]

When I comment out the parts of the application that require torch and remove it from requirements.txt, it works fine. What can I do to ensure that torch is installed like the other modules in requirements.txt? [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zw99PZLJx45uk_6WgcExuuSQsJLJzOn_/view?usp=sharing) is the link to requirements.txt

Comment: When uploading project to AWS. are you sure you are reinstalling the packages in the requeminets.txt ?

Comment: I think so. From a tutorial, "Elastic Beanstalk uses requirements.txt to determine which package to install on the EC2 instances that run your application.". Maybe I need to make an entirely new AWS environment since I changed the requirements.

Comment: yes. it is more likely that you are not installing the packages again. You can check if he is installing the packages again in the logs or in the console

Comment: Can you post your requiremetns.txt as actuall text file, not screenshot.

Comment: @josuedjh how can i check that from the logs or the console?

Comment: yes, updated @Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default torch will require **CUDA** and **GPU**. Depending on your ec2 instance this may not be viable option, thus leading to the errors you are observing.

You can install [non-cuda version](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#mac-anaconda) of torch as follows for tests and see if this will have any benefits:

```
pip3 install torch==1.5.1+cpu torchvision==0.6.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```